# Any script to make IE show CSS3 / HTML5 same as Firefox / Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I designed a HTML Webpage, and everything look perfect on Chrome and Firefox.
But on IE9, its show very bad >_<

I wonder, do we have any script or some ways to auto set / fix those thing for IE?

Comment: You mean a magical "fix everything for me" button? Would be nice, wouldn't it?

Comment: my URL is: http://support.crosspath.com/support/index-broken.php on Chrome and FF, look good, but IE look stupid >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should include the HTML 5 Doctype.  When i loaded the page in IE9, it was forcing the page to Quirks mode.  looks mostly ok when I change it to IE9 standards mode.

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Also, you could try using the meta tag:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >`

or

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >`

to force the browser mode to IE9.

Comment: Glad this worked for you.  Just looked at your site and noticed that you've included both of the meta tags.  My recommendation would be to only include one.

Answer (score 1):

I got two, two word phrases for you bro... 'Progressive Enhancement' and 'Graceful Degradation'

Answer (score 1):

Please validate your page first. No proper doctype deceleration. Browser will render  your page in QuirksMode. I think some tags also missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any script to do so... But your problem may depend on what properties are you using and if they are supported by IE9. You may want to check [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp) site for CSS properties support

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what feature you use. For example if you use a progressbar you can emulate one with javascript. Alternatives are also called polyfill. A good link to use could be [the html5 please website](http://html5please.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you may want to consider using these:

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

and:

http://modernizr.com/